# Unable to import `floatbox` from `easygui` module

Tags: python, easygui

When I am running my script in `CMD`, it displays error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'floatbox' from 'easygui'`

So I tried uninstalling and installing `easygui` several times, but same result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to include more than just the error message you are getting, consider a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Easygui 0.98.1 does not have a floatbox. However, there is a simple solution, read the data as string and then convert it to float:

```
import easygui as eg
value = eg.enterbox(msg="Introduce a value")
value = float(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you researched `easygui` poorly and don't know options of it.

`Easygui` doesn't have `floatbox` option and I think it will come in next update: `easygui 0.99`.

So you are trying impossible thing. Read docs at [Easygui 0.98.1 Latest](https://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Easygui doesn't have floatbox option (mentioned in other answers too)
but you can do like this method when insert '1' this mean insert '0.001'
lowerbound and upperbound change on your range

```
import easygui as eui
msg = eui.integerbox("Message",
                      title="your_title", lowerbound=0, 
                      upperbound=10000000)

float_number = msg/1000
print(float_number)
```

output:

```
0.001
```

Answer (score -1):

The current easygui version (as of 10/10/2023) does not have a floatbox. Rather than reading the data as a string and then converting it to a float, a more efficient solution is to convert the data to a float immediately.

```
import easygui as eg
value = float(eg.enterbox(msg="Insert value here"))
```

Comment: I'm voting to delete this because it's the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61799206/7758804). Don't add **thank you**, or **confirmation** answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from quality contributions, you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you found helpful. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/35108818)